# Как определить, какая из камер на смартфоне в данный момент задействована?

Tags: javascript, html, web-camera

Сразу после того, как юзер перешел на страницу, у него включается камера(в приоритете — задняя, если имеется)
Заранее благодарю за помощь

Comment: попробуйте воспользоваться этим https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/enumerateDevices О результатах, можете напистаь здесь